# Does db.create_all() check if the database exists?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I checked the docs but it didn't say anything much about it, weirdly.

If I call `db.create_all()`, does there need to be some sort of check as to whether the database already exists, lest it be overwritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [only creates tables](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L922); so it is up to you to make sure the database is already created.

The database has to exist and if the table already exists, you'll receive an error from the database. It will not overwrite or delete tables.